# How to POST request using curl with authentication

Tags: bash, unix, curl

I have API http://x.xx.x.xx:xxxx/api/v1/clusters/Cluster12/commands/restart for restarting cluster.

I want to use the next command:
curl --request POST 'http://x.xx.x.xx:xxxx/api/v1/clusters/Cluster12/commands/restart'

But got the message "Full authentication is required to access this resource"

Answer (score 0):

With Variables:

```
curl --data "var1=val1&var2=val2" http://x.xx.x.xx:xxxx/api/v1/clusters/Cluster12/commands/restart
```

Without Variables:

```
curl -X POST http://x.xx.x.xx:xxxx/api/v1/clusters/Cluster12/commands/restart
```

May be you can use this?

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
curl -u username:passwd -X POST 'http://x.xx.x.xx:xxxx/api/v1/clusters/Cluster12/commands/restart'
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for help. Now it is working. I should use some arguments from API
curl -u username:password -H "Accept: application/json"  -X POST -d '{"SomeArgument":"true"}' http://masterIP:xxxx/api/v1/clusters/Cluster12/commands/restart